# jQuery click event not firing custom event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a jQuery library that dynamically creates a link with a click event like:

```
$parent.append('<div class="add-row"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Add another contact</a></div>');
addButton = $parent.find("div:last a");

addButton.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    load_contact_creation_form();
});
```

I want to add some code to my page so when the URL contains a specific flag, the `addButton.click` event is fired automatically.

Inspecting with the Firefox/Chrome debug tool, I can easily find the link with:

```
$('.add-row a')
```

However, attempting to using `$('.add-row a').click()` to click it does not trigger the custom 'click' event.

Why is there a disparity between `.click()` and a real mouse-click? How do I trigger the custom `click` event handler in this case? The code that generates the link is an external library, so I can't easily modify it.

Comment: you said that it doesn't fire when you call `.click()`, but didn't mention if it's firing when you actually click on it. does it?

Comment: it might have something to do with your `href="javascript:void(0)"`. it might be calling `void(0)` instead of your click event.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work as expected for me. Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d3s8topL/

```
$("#addDiv").click(function (){

    $("#test").append('<div class="add-row"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Add another contact</a></div>');
    var addButton = $("#test").find("div:last a");

    addButton.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("asdasd");
    });

});

$("#triggerClick").click(function () {

    $(".add-row a").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `MutationOberserver` but,Mutation Observer API is only available in newer versions of Google Chrome (>= 18) and Mozillza Firefox (>= 14).  So you could use a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe) for that. Using the plugin, you could do

```
$('.add-row').observe("childlist", "a", function(){
   $(this).click(); // trigger
});
```